# outputting data into table

Tags: php, mysql, json

the code below will echo yes, no, maybe or text from a db. I want the output to be in a table like this

```
echo "<tr><td><b>OUTPUT HERE</b></td></tr>";
```

Here is the full code.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT stats.*
  FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic stats
       JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref refs on stats.statistic_ref_id = refs.statistic_ref_id
WHERE refs.user_id= $current_user->ID  && refs.quiz_id= 5");
foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr><td><b></b></td></tr>";
$a = $row->answer_data;
$b = json_decode($a, true);
if($b[0] == 1){ echo 'Yes'; }
if($b[1] == 1){ echo 'No'; }
if($b[2] == 1){ echo 'Maybe'; }
if(count($b) == 1){ echo '$row->answer_data'; }
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just echo the opening tags, then the content, the close them.

```
<?php
echo "<tr><td><b>";
// Echo query results 
echo "</b></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
 if(count($b) == 1){//maybe > 0 ?
  echo "<tr><td><b>";
  $a = $row->answer_data;
  $b = json_decode($a, true);
  if($b[0] == 1){ echo 'Yes'; }
  if($b[1] == 1){ echo 'No'; }
  if($b[2] == 1){ echo 'Maybe'; }
  echo $row->answer_data;
  echo "</b></td></tr>";
 }

}
```

Comment: thanx, julien just beat you to it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this : it will do the trick.**

```
 <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT stats.* FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic stats JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref refs on stats.statistic_ref_id = refs.statistic_ref_id WHERE refs.user_id= $current_user->ID  && refs.quiz_id= 5");

    foreach($result as $row) {   
     $a = $row->answer_data;
     $b = json_decode($a, true);
     $myOutput;
     if($b[0] == 1){ $myOutput = 'Yes'; }
     if($b[1] == 1){ $myOutput = 'No'; }
     if($b[2] == 1){ $myOutput = 'Maybe'; }
     if(count($b) == 1){ 
       echo "<tr><td><b>".$myOutput."</b></td></tr>";
     }
    }
 ?>
```